# Read the value of Parent state and pass Boolean to Child Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble learning how to pass data between parent and child in React Native.

In my parent component I have a state property (audioPlaying) which is a Boolean value.

```
state = {
    //The title informs the Button and TitleArea components
    title: 'hello',
    audioPlaying: false,
};
```

I'd like to change that value on the press of a button (onPress).

```
<Button
    title={this.state.title}
    onPress={this.playPauseHandler}
    audioPlaying={this.state.audioPlaying}
/>
```

...by calling the playPauseHandler.

```
playPauseHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        audioPlaying: !prevState.audioPlaying
    }));
}
```

Then in my child (Button) Component I want to evaluate the audioPlaying state property. If it's true, I want to show one things and false I want to show something else.

```
<View style={styles.playBtnStyle}>
    {this.props.audioPlaying === false ? (
        <MaterialIcons
            name='play-arrow'
            size={50}
            color="#87888C"
        />
        ) : (
        <MaterialIcons
            name='pause'
            size={50}
            color="#87888C"
        />
        )}
    }
</View>
```

However, when I run this I get undefined for the value of audioPlaying.
[React Native Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr18u.png)

Here are the full files for both:

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import Carousel from './src/components/Carousel/Carousel';
import Button from './src/components/Button/Button';
import TitleArea from './src/components/TitleArea/TitleArea';
import MapArea from './src/components/MapArea/MapArea';

const styles = {
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
 },
 playArea: {
  flex: 1,
 },
};

export default class App extends Component {
 state = {
  //The title informs the Button and TitleArea components
  title: 'hello',
  audioPlaying: false,
 };

 playPauseHandler = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
   audioPlaying: !prevState.audioPlaying
  }));
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <TitleArea title={this.state.title} />
    <StatusBar hidden={false} />
    <Carousel />
    <MapArea />
    <Button
     title={this.state.title}
     onPress={this.playPauseHandler}
     audioPlaying={this.state.audioPlaying}
    />
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Button.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const height = width * 0.2;
const styles = {
 textStyle: {
  color: '#87888C',
  fontSize: 18,
  fontWeight: '600',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  alignSelf: 'center',
 },
 buttonContainer: {
  height,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  alignItems: 'center',
 },
 playBtnStyle: {
  marginLeft: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
 },
 childStyle: {
  flex: 1,
 },
};

const button = (props) => {
 return (
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
   <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={styles.playBtnStyle}>
     {this.props.audioPlaying === false ? (
      <MaterialIcons
       name='play-arrow'
       size={50}
       color="#87888C"
      />
      ) : (
      <MaterialIcons
       name='pause'
       size={50}
       color="#87888C"
      />
      )}
     }
    </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>

   <View style={styles.childStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Chapter 1: {props.title}</Text>
   </View>
  </View>
 );
}

export default button;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `this` in the context of button. That is just a function returning JSX.
Instead, use `props`

```
<View style={styles.playBtnStyle}>
  {props.audioPlaying === false ? (
    <MaterialIcons
      name='play-arrow'
      size={50}
      color="#87888C"
    />
  ) : (
    <MaterialIcons
      name='pause'
      size={50}
      color="#87888C"
    />
  )}
</View>
```

Comment: When I do this, the button still doesn't change.

Comment: I'm expecting to change the state value on every press. Maybe it's not doing that?

Comment: props is just receiving a value though. Which is why I'm confused. It's just reading state. onPress is calling setState which will force a rerender from my understanding.

Comment: Instead of using `setState( prevState => {audioPlaying: !prevState.audioPlaying  } )`, try `setState({ audioPlaying : !this.state.audioPlaying })`. I ran a test in jsFiddle and that made a difference for me, although im unsure why at this point.

Comment: It's still not working for me. I logged state inside of my Button component and found that my "audioPlaying" state is passing from parent to child. However, my onPress prop isn't calling the function like I thought it would. I've tried this but it still didn't work. onPress={() => this.playPauseHandler()}

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved my own problem! *(step one to being a developer)*

Two issues:

**Capturing Touch Events**

React Native has what's called Touchables. According to the documentation these are "wrappers that make views respond properly to touches".

TouchableOpacity, the one I'm using:

> On press down, the opacity of the wrapped view is decreased, dimming it. Opacity is controlled by wrapping the children in an Animated.View, which is added to the view hierarchy.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpress

All Touchables accept the onPress prop. So by adding the onPress prop to the Touchable, I'm able to capture the touch event instead of just firing it.

**Passing Callback to Parent**

This article helped me understand more about how a parent function can be called from a child.

https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766

So I'm calling playPause() (I renamed the prop and destructured it) in TouchableOpacity, which fires from a touch event causing state to change and component to re-render.

```js
const button = (props) => {
  const {
    title,
    audioPlaying,
    playPause,
  } = props;
  return (
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => playPause()}>
                <View style={styles.playBtnStyle}>
                    {audioPlaying === false ? (
                        <MaterialIcons
                            name='play-arrow'
                            size={50}
                            color="#87888C"
                        />
                    ) : (
                            <MaterialIcons
                                name='pause'
                                size={50}
                                color="#87888C"
                            />
                    )
                    }
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.childStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                  Chapter 1:
                    {title}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Glad it's working! One small change I would recommend to clean up your code is `<MaterialIcons
                            name={audioPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play-arrow'}
                            size={50}
                            color="#87888C"
                        />`

Comment: Oh yea that's right. I was reading about "truthy and falsy" and worried that the prop by itself might be valued truthy and confuse me/make it harder to debug.